# Sign a document with developers account signature automatically in DocuSignApi call

Tags: docusignapi

I have an document , which needs the signature from the developers account on default, how can I achieve this. I have successfully added a document and have generated the view url to be sent. But I want to add the signature of the developers account by default , cant seem to find a way to do this.

Comment: Hi Jyoti, it sounds like you want to automatically add the signature via the API. This is not possible - signing involves manual interaction by a user with the document.

Answer (score 0):

As Luis mentions in his comment above, it's not possible to automatically (programatically) add signatures to documents for some recipient(s) while requiring that other recipient(s) sign using DocuSign.  You have a couple of options to get the developer's (i.e., sender's) signature on the documents:

1. Include the Developer (Sender) as the first recipient in the Envelope's workflow. (They'll sign using DocuSign, just as all other recipients will.)  This is your best option, because you'll get all of the normal security and audit trail functionality that DocuSign provides for all signers.
2. Burn the Developer's (i.e., Sender's) signature into the document(s) prior to adding the documents to DocuSign.  i.e., the signature will already be on the documents when you add them to DocuSign. Not a great option, IMO.

Keep in mind that automatically applying someone's signature to documents (i.e., either programatically or by burning the signature into the documents before adding them to DocuSign) somewhat nullifies the intended effect of a signature -- i.e., a signature typically implies one's agreement/consent -- but if the signature is applied without any action on behalf of the signer, then is agreement/consent truly in effect?